# How to select the latest node.js v6 version using n?

Tags: javascript, node.js, n

With `nvm` tool one can execute `nvm use 6` to select the latest installed node.js v6. How would I do the same using [the `n` CLI tool?](https://github.com/tj/n)

The command(s) will be executed on the CI.

Comment: type `n latest` or `n 6.9.2` ?

Comment: @DennyHiu `n 6.9.2` won't install the latest v6. And `n latest` would install v7 or v8 or whatever is latest. But I need the latest of the v6 (like 6.42.511 or whatever it will be in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n 6` will install (activate) the newest version of node 6.

Or `n install 6` if you prefer a more readable command.

You can specify partial version numbers with `n` and it will use the newest matching version.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way we can achieve it,

```
  n ls                           Output the versions of node available
```

Select the one which you need and install by generally by regular n method ?

```
  n <version>                    Install node <version>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Forgot to mention that it has to be a single command executed by out CI.